# Cant load content with ajax into popup.html chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load some images into my popup but I cannot. Nothing will load here is my code

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../ads/ad1.png',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#latest-ads').html(data);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '../ads/ad2.png',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#latest-ads').html(data);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '../ads/ad3.png',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#latest-ads').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

It gave no errors. But the images would not load either. Those are the relative version of the links. I do not want to give out my domain name as it is not out yet.

Comment: Did you check the paths and verify they were right?

Comment: Yup yup, verified correctly. Plus if they weren't they'd usually give a message in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

chrome.browserAction.onClicked - this event will not fire in the popup.

Firstly, because popup content will be loaded after you clicked on the icon.
Secondly, the doc says: *"This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup."*

So just put your code on top or to the $(document).ready() listener.

Relative urls will be resolved to your chrome extension root folder and extension will try to load images from there.